# JavaScript calling array values in two different contexts

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am having trouble understanding how to call specific array values:
I have commented out the questions in the code.  Please take a look and let me know why the array produces one result within the function, while producing a different result outside of it.  To run the code, please use a website like repl.it

```
var passengers = [ ["Thomas", "Meeks"], 
                   ["Gregg", "Pollack"], 
                   ["Christine", "Wong"], 
                   ["Dan", "McGaw"] ];

var results = passengers.map(function (array) {
    // The following prints out the first names--the entire first column.  Why? 
    console.log(array[0]);
});

console.log(); // Just empty space

// Why is the following only printin the first row of passengers (which it should), but the array[0] printed out the entirety of the first column?  
console.log(passengers[0]);
```

Comment: Because in the first `console.log`, you're accessing the first member of each nested Array. What output were you expecting for that? The `array` parameter represents `passengers[0]` then `passengers[1]`, `passengers[2]` and so on..., so `array[0]` is `passengers[0][0]` then `passengers[1][0]` ...

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of arrays, so when you call `map` here:

```
var results = passengers.map(function (array) {
    // The following prints out the first names--the entire first column.  Why? 
    console.log(array[0]);
});
```

It's looping through the outer array. The parameter that gets passed into the function is the element of the array that you're looping through, in this case, the inner array. So the `console.log(array[0])` is printing the first element of the inner array.

In other words, this code is roughly equivalent to:

```
 console.log(passengers[0][0]);
 console.log(passengers[1][0]);
 console.log(passengers[2][0]);
 console.log(passengers[3][0]);
```

Notice that in this example, I'm only iterating through the outer array (the first index). The inner array index stays at zero.

But later where you have

```
console.log(passengers[0]);
```

It's simply printing the first element from the outer array, which is the entire first inner array.

**Further Reading**

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Why is it looping through the array in the first place?  I never set up any loops.  I expected to get the same result for both array[0] and passengers[0].

Comment: @AdiedX It's looping through the array because that's what `map` does. I've included a link to the MDN documentation of that method if you'd like more information.

Comment: @AdiedX You seem confused about what map does. It does not create a map(key-value pairs) or parse a 2D array into a map. Map loops through an array returns a new array after processing every element in the array with the provided function. Its the map from the popular Map-Reduce terminology.